# Rails routes do not contain id in that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use rails 5 and setting route, type rake routes in console and result is:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
new_report_templates GET    /report_templates/new(.:format)  report_templates#new
edit_report_templates GET    /report_templates/edit(.:format) report_templates#edit
report_templates GET    /report_templates(.:format)      report_templates#show
                  PATCH  /report_templates(.:format)      report_templates#update
                  PUT    /report_templates(.:format)      report_templates#update
                  DELETE /report_templates(.:format)      report_templates#destroy
                  POST   /report_templates(.:format)      report_templates#create
```

It's so weird to see that result routes do not have id in url template. My route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :report_templates
end
```

I use gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'. So my question is: why my result routes do not contain id in that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because your are using [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID.

Change your routes to use [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for certain routes to contain the `id`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :report_templates
end
```